# Can Mono port non xna phone app to windows 8 phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, mono, xna, windows-phone-8

I'm planning on making a soundboard for windows phone 7 and then hoping to port to windows phone 8. I've had plenty of experience with XNA for game creation but have never made a non game app. It seems easier to do it as a normal phone app using Expression Blend so i can take advantage of using xml.

The question is can you use Mono to port a normal windows phone 7 app this or would it be simpler to just use XNA and port to windows phone 8?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need to port a Windows Phone 7 app to Windows Phone 8. If you want to add Windows Phone 8 specific features you can do something similar to what is [described in this article](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!co-development-and-porting-guide.html).

Comment: wow. That's really useful. Thanks very much. On your examples are just using windows phone application project or an expression blend project?

Comment: Windows Phone projects can open in both Visual Studio and Blend.